# Convert C to MPI API C Program

Tags: mpi

How do we convert c Program with user defined function to a Parallel Program using MPI API to C. A Demo would be more useful

Thank you.
Hari

Comment: This depends entirely on what the function does and how it can be parallelized. There's no step by step guide that will automagically convert any serial program into a parallel one using MPI. OpenMP is a lot easier to use, but be advised that it splits work into threads, not processes, so it cannot be used in a distributed environment.

Comment: @suszterpatt There are OpenMP implementations that can work in a distributed memory cluster, e.g Intel's Cluster OpenMP.

Comment: @shawn but why would some one will use OpenMP over the distributed memory model ? is it to make a common programming language for parallel programming ?

Comment: @Peeyush OpenMP uses a directive-based approach to automatically parallelise loops, making it a quick an easy way to achieve some parallelism for compute intensive loops (or blocks of code) without rewriting the code. Naturally, for good performance, some tweaking is require which requires a good understanding of your code and the OpenMP itself.

Comment: @ShawnChin: The cluster OpenMP implementations in software are a performance disaster.  People have been working on this for decades and it still doesn't work, except for problems that require so little communications that it would be trivial to write in MPI.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon what you are trying to execute in parallel and what are your requirements.

There are lot of good tutorials available.

Here's a simple hello world program :

```cpp
#include "stdio.h"
#include "mpi.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int id, nprocs;
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);

  printf("Hello World from proc %d out of %d!\n", id, nprocs);

  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

The compile it as following

```
usr@xbc:~> mpicc -Wall -Werror -o mpihello mpihello.c
```

To Run it on 2 separate machines as

```
usr@xbc:~> mpirun_rsh  -ssh -np 2 node0 node1 /home/xbc/mpihello
```

or

```
usr@xbc:~> mpirun_rsh  -hostfile hostlist -n 2 /home/xbc/mpihello
```

where your `hostlist` file would have 2 entries as `node0` and `node`

To Run it on the same machine as 2 processes

```
usr@xbc:~> mpirun_rsh  -ssh -np 2 node0:1 /home/xbc/mpihello
```

or

```
usr@xbc:~> mpirun_rsh  -hostfile hostlist -n 2 /home/xbc/mpihello
```

where your `hostlist` file would have 1 entry as `node0:1`

The output put would a Hello world with Ranks as `0` and `1` from either 2 machines or 2 processes depending upon how you run it.

Now you can run MPI over TCP/IP  or MPI over IP over IB(InfiniBand) or MPI over IB Over Ethernet or in many other ways depending upon your requirements.

You will have to configure the mpi compilation and installation accordingly.